# Finding numbers where each digit of the number is an even number

Tags: python-3.x

I'm trying to write code that will take a range and list the numbers that are only made up of even numbers (numbers like 88, 202 , 468).

The code works for three digit ranges, but if I make the range (1, 401) or (10, 401), it does not work because it doesn't have three digits.

```
items = []
for i in range(100, 401):
    s = str(i)
    if (int(s[0])%2==0) and (int(s[1])%2==0) and (int(s[2])%2==0):
        items.append(s)
print( ",".join(items))
```

When I make the limit only two digits, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 4, in <module>
    if (int(s[0])%2==0) and (int(s[1])%2==0) and (int(s[2])%2==0):
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `itertools.takewhile`:

```
digits = [88, 202 , 468, 1024, 999, 2067, 0]

from itertools import takewhile

for d in digits:
    filtered = ''.join(takewhile(lambda c: int(c) % 2 == 0, str(d)))
    if not filtered:
        continue
    if int(filtered) == d:
        print(d)
```

prints:

```
88
202
468
0
```

Version 2 (using `itertools.zip_longest`):

```
digits = [88, 202 , 468, 1024, 999, 2067, 0]

from itertools import takewhile, zip_longest

for d in digits:
    if all(i==j for i, j in zip_longest(str(d), takewhile(lambda c: int(c) % 2 == 0, str(d)))):
        print(d)
```

Prints:

```
88
202
468
0
```

Version 3 (without `itertools`):

```
digits = [88, 202 , 468, 1024, 999, 2067, 0]

for d in digits:
    if all(int(i) / 2 == int(i) // 2 for i in str(d)):
        print(d)
```

Prints:

```
88
202
468
0
```

Answer (score 0):

This is because you always try to check the 3rd digit using `s[2]` in this line:

```
if (int(s[0])%2==0) and (int(s[1])%2==0) and (int(s[2])%2==0):
```

to make it generic, use the [`all`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#all) function with a list comprehension, such as:

```
if all(int(digit) % 2 == 0 for digit in s):
```

Answer (score 0):

Your error stems from unconditionally accessing the string of a number at its third place - *even* if the number is shorter.

You have to check if lenght of the string == 3 to find only 3-digit solutions.

If you want to get even numbers you can either

- check length == 3
- convert the number into a string
- convert each digit back into a number and check all for modulo 2

or

- check length == 3
- convert the number into a string
- check each character against a set of even digit-strings

Converting *digits back into integers and using modular 2* to test it is more costly, hence the method c_hecking the character against a set of allowed characters_ is about 25% faster (see timings below):

```
items = []
even = set("24680")
for i in range(10, 1401):
    s = str(i)
    if len(s)==3 and all(c in even for c in s):
        items.append(s)
print( ",".join(items))
```

Output:

```
200,202,204,206,208,220,222,224,226,228,240,242,244,246,248,260,262,264,266,268,280,
282,284,286,288,400,402,404,406,408,420,422,424,426,428,440,442,444,446,448,460,462,
464,466,468,480,482,484,486,488,600,602,604,606,608,620,622,624,626,628,640,642,644,
646,648,660,662,664,666,668,680,682,684,686,688,800,802,804,806,808,820,822,824,826,
828,840,842,844,846,848,860,862,864,866,868,880,882,884,886,888
```

---

**Comparison of character-in-set vs. number mod 2 == 0:**

```
def with_set():
    items = []
    even = set("24680")
    for i in range(10, 1401):
        s = str(i)
        if len(s)==3 and all(c in even for c in s):
            items.append(s)
    return items

def with_mod():             
    items = []
    for i in range(10, 1401):
        s = str(i)
        if len(s)==3 and all(int(c)%2==0 for c in s):
            items.append(s)
    return items


import timeit
# try both methods 1000 times, print time
print("Set: ", timeit.timeit(with_set, number=1000))
print("Mod: ", timeit.timeit(with_mod, number=1000))
```

Output timings:

```
Set:  0.9209150870001395
Mod:  1.2408415259997128
```